# Unable to use BackHandler for Perticular Screen Using react-native

Tags: react-native

I want to create Backhandler functionality for only one screen. I have more than one screen and I want to show the backhandler popup message after the user successfully login. This code works properly, but the problem is that this code is used for all screens. Just want to show popup message only on home screen. Please make any suggestions as to how I can resolve this issue.

```
 componentDidMount() {
  BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
 }

 componentWillUnmount() {
 BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
 }
  handleBackPress = () => {
  Alert.alert(
  'Exit',
  'Do you want to Exit App?',
  [
   { text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => { return null } },
  {
    text: 'Confirm', onPress: async () => {
      BackHandler.exitApp();
    }
  },
 ],
  {
   cancelable: false
  }
  )
  return true;
};
```

I am navigating the screens with the help of this code.Plese Check my code.

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator(); 
 function App() {
 return (

 <NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="AuthLoading">                 
    <Stack.Screen name="AuthLoading" component={AuthLoadingScreen}  options= 
    {{headerShown:false}} />
    <Stack.Screen name="LOGIN" component={Login} options={{headerShown:false}} />
   <Stack.Screen name= "Register" component={Registration} options={{headerShown:false}} />       
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{headerShown:false}}  />     
     </Stack.Navigator>
   </NavigationContainer>
   );
  }
 export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

A screen is not unmounted when a new screen is pushed, so hooking on to `componentWillUnmount` will not work for your situation.

User React Navigation's Navigation events to listen for `blur` and `focus` events instead. - [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/)

```
const focusUnsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
});

const blurUnsubscribe = navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
});
```

(call focus/blur unsubscribe in `componentWillUnmount`)

Comment: Sorry,I did not understand, please can you implement your answer in my code how do I use. ?